# Why is Android Studio in VirtualBox unable to use a phone it is connected to?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualbox

I'm running Android Studio on a Kubuntu virtual machine in VirtualBox. My phone is connected through a usb cable. Developer mode is enabled. The phone appears in Android Studio, as you can see below.

But somehow I can't run an app on it. Is it possible Windows is somehow hoarding the connection, and that I can free it? Not sure what else to try.

[image]

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Plugging the cable out and in again seems to have fixed it